# QTreeView: resizeRowsToContents equivalent or how to word-wrap text in rows

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` with more than one column (like a table). Columns in the tree have a fixed size. I need to resize row heights and use multi-lined text like `QTableView::resizeRowsToContents`.
How can I do this?

I've tried using a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` with reimplemented `sizeHint`, but I don't know how to calculate multiline text block height with known width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `QStyledItemDelegate` is the right approach. In your `sizeHint` function, you can use the style options [text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionviewitem.html#text-var) with the [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) class:

```
QSize MyItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
    QSize baseSize = this->QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index);
    baseSize.setHeight(10000);//something very high, or the maximum height of your text block

    QFontMetrics metrics(option.font);
    QRect outRect = metrics.boundingRect(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), baseSize), Qt::AlignLeft, option.text);
    baseSize.setHeight(outRect.height());
    return baseSize;
}
```

**Note:** Right now I cannot test this, but it should work. You may have to tweak the call to `metrics.boundingRect` if the output does not fit your needs

**EDIT:**
It seems the `sizeHint` will be only called once to create the initial layout, but not after resizing the columns.

A final Idea could be to override the `QAbstractItemModel::data` function to return the desired size using `Qt::SizeHintRole`. You could either add it to your existing model or provide a proxy-model to do this:

```
QSize MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override {
    switch(role) {
        //...
    case Qt::SizeHintRole:
    {
        QSize baseSize(getFixedWidth(index.column()), baseSize.setHeight(10000));//something very high, or the maximum height of your text block

        QFontMetrics metrics(this->data(index, Qt::FontRole).value<QFont>());
        QRect outRect = metrics.boundingRect(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), baseSize), Qt::AlignLeft, this->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole)));
        baseSize.setHeight(outRect.height());
        return baseSize;
    }
        //...
    }
}
```

Important: Everytime your view gets resized, you will have to emit the `dataChanged` signal for all those items. `getFixedWidth` is something you will have to implement to return the current width of the given column.

Comment: OK, it works! But how to make cells resize again on sectioin resized?

Comment: I'm not shure what you mean? resizing a header section?

Comment: Yes, rows resized once on load, but did nothing when resizing header section and column width changing

Comment: Try to repaint the treeview after every each time the section is resized. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionResized If the does not work, too, I maybe have an idea...

Comment: Tried
connect(header(), SIGNAL(sectionResized(int,int,int)), this, SLOT(repaint()));
Still no changes